NetxJS не правильно показывает спец. знаки (&lt;, &gt; итд...)
Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как рендерить специальные коды вместо символов на странице?
Пример:
const Component = () => {
    const username = '&lt;Alex&gt;' // Данные из сервера

    return (
        <>
         // Вывод &lt;Alex&gt; вместо <Alex>
         <input value={username} />
         // Так тоже не работает
         <div>{username}</div>
         // Так работает. Вывод: <Alex>
         <div>&lt;Alex&gt;</div>
        </>
    )
}

Проблема решается если использовать prop dangerouslySetInnerHTML, но dangerouslySetInnerHTML не работает с тегом <input />.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248849/converting-sanitised-html-back-to-displayable-html

Правильно — возвращать с сервера данные в нужном виде.
